# Do coloratura sopranos sing the high F (F6) in mixed voice or head voice?

Tags: voice

I'm confused about this.  When googling about coloratura sopranos, wiki and several other sites say that coloratura sopranos can sing to the high F (with some just below or above that, of course).  Do they mean they can fully support an F6 with a strong head voice? Or are they saying these women can sing in mixed voice up to F6?

Because for sopranos in general it's always C6, which quite a few sopranos can mix/belt. And when looking at leggero tenors, who are said to be the male counterpart to coloratura sopranos, we can sing in mix up to F5, and a few (even though it's rare) can get up higher to A or B5. So is this the same thing?

Just wondering.

Comment: Since the 'break point' is different for each person, there probably isn't a concrete answer.